# Find rebase point

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-reset

Say I have this:

```
I1 -- I2 -- I3 
 \            \
  F1 -- F2 -- ? -- F3 -- F4 -- F5
```

I created a new feature branch, F, I made commit F1 and F2, and then after that I wanted to incorporate changes from the integration branch to prevent conflicts.

So I do:

```
git fetch origin I
git checkout F
git rebase origin/I
```

So what it should look like now is something like this:

```
I1 -- I2 -- I3
               \
               F1 -- F2 -- F3 -- F4 -- F5
```

my question is - now I want to squash commits F1-F5, into one commit. How can I *safely* squash the commits?

I can do `git reset --soft x`, but what is `x`? How can I find which commit to go back to? I don't want to lose any of the history from the integration branch.

In English, I suppose it would be the oldest commit on my branch that isn't in the integration branch, but also where that commit is younger than any commits from the integration branch. (?) The latter scenario might occur if I do a `git merge` instead of `git rebase` (by accident).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Try `git fetch && GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '' 's/^pick/squash/'" git rebase -i @{u}` (you can squeeze this into an alias, shell or Git-to-shell).

#### Long

Consider the following: When you run `git rebase`, *you tell `git rebase` where to put the copies*.  That is, you run:

```
git checkout $branch
git rebase $onto
```

where `$branch` is the name of your branch, and `$onto` is the thing that specifies how to do the rebase.  Since the copies go *after* the commit specified by `$onto`, `$onto` is automatically the correct point for your `git reset --soft`.

If you have `git pull --rebase` run `git rebase` for you, you give up direct control of `$onto` here.  The `git pull` command first runs `git fetch $remote` for some `$remote`, then uses the fetched information that `git fetch` records (in `$GIT_DIR/FETCH_HEAD`) as the `$onto` parameter.

There is a bit of extra complication here due to the fork-point code, but in modern Git, you have the advantage that `git fetch` will update `$upstream` where `$upstream` is the upstream of the current branch, after which `git rebase` will use `$upstream` and do all the fork-point stuff automatically, so that `$upstream` is still correct.  In this case, using:

```
. git-sh-setup
branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD) || die 'not currently on a branch'
remote=$(git config --get branch.$branch.remote) || die 'current branch has no upstream'
git fetch $remote && git rebase || die 'fetch or rebase failed'
git reset --soft $upstream && git commit
```

as your script (named, e.g., `git-rebase-and-squash` in your `$PATH` and run as `git rebase-and-squash`) would mostly do the trick.

Rather than using `reset --soft` and `git commit` directly, though, you might want to make the last line read:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '' 's/^pick/squash/'" git rebase -i $upstream
```

which would convert all the `pick`s to `squash`es for you, and in this case you would not even need the earlier `git rebase`, so that the whole script collapses down to `git fetch` followed by `git rebase -i @{upstream}`.  (Whether you still want to automate the sequence editing is up to you.)

If you don't mind slightly misleading error messages, you don't need the checking either.  Running `git fetch` will fetch from `origin` by default, and `@upstream` will fail noisily if there is no current branch *or* if the current branch has no upstream, so this can be reduced to a two-command-long script or alias:

```
git fetch && GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i '' 's/^pick/squash/'" git rebase -i @{u}
```

Comment: so to this *programmatically*, it seems like this is all that is needed: `git fetch origin dev; git rebase dev; git reset --soft dev;` is that right? In other words, as long I as I do the rebase before the reset, I should be good.

Comment: looks like the above comment is OK

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Just remember to check for failure-exit from each command, since each one can fail for a variety of reasons: e.g., `git fetch` might fail to fetch because the network is down, or rebase might hit a conflict and need human help. (If the soft reset fails, which is the least likely of all, it doesn't matter so much since it's the last step anyway!)

Comment: yes you are right. however, going back to original question. is there a point to rebasing the feature branch onto the integration branch? The only purpose I can see is to avoid unnecessary merge commits. However, if you just do `git reset --soft I`, instead of doing the rebase beforehand, when you eventually merge the feature branch into the integration branch, I don't see how rebasing beforehand matters

Comment: It all depends on when, where, and how you want to do the work. If you are going to use `git merge --squash` to merge the work and kill off the feature branch, you can do that at the end if you want to defer all the work. If you want to do the work earlier, you can rebase at any time. So, decide when and how and where you wish to do the work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to squash via a soft reset, then do:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~5
```

This will move the HEAD pointer from its current position at `F5` back to the `I3` commit.  But, a soft reset *won't* touch both the working directory and stage.  So the net effect will be that your stage will reflect the 5 `F` commits.  Then, when you commit, you will effectively squash those 5 commits down to one:

```
git commit -m 'squashed 5 F commits'
```

This leaves you with:

```
I1 -- I2 -- I3 -- C
```

As an alternative, you could also do an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

You would change each commit you wanted to squash from `pick` to `squash`, and then complete the rebase.

Comment: Upvoted, but I need to do this programmatically dogg. Even if I were to do it manually, I don't know where I would get the magic number 5 from, do you?

Comment: `programmatically dogg` ... I didn't know that dogs could program, but that aside, my answer _is_ a programmatic answer.  If you're using Git from some tool other than the command line, then do tell us what you are using.

Comment: Dogs can't program, but doggs can. Anyway, in real life, how would you determine how many commits to go back? Going back 5 commits isn't always the right answer obviously.

Comment: I get it now.  The answer is that you need to find some way to know how many commits back to reset.  For example, if the `F` commits are always guaranteed to come from you, and the `I` commits to come from someone else, then you could go back as far as needed to hit a commit _other_ than yourself.

Comment: Right, I keep going backwards in the git log until I hit a commit that's already in the integration branch I guess?

Comment: Yes, this is the only thing which comes to mind in general.  But most of the time when you do a delicate rebasing operation like this, you would want to have the full history in front of you.

Comment: Ok thx, so yeah I am looking for a way to programmatically find that point, such a thing might already be a Git utility, I don't know.

Comment: if you didn't see it, the infamous @torek added an answer